# Issue while applying Min() on column with datatype "timestamp without time zone"

Tags: postgresql

I have a created a table named event with column named 'event_timestamp' with datatype 'timestamp without time zone having values as below-

| event_timestamp |
| --- |
| 2021-09-28 07:51:20.516921 |
| 2021-10-08 07:51:20.517288 |

I need to find the minimum value.

```
select min(event_timestamp) as min from public.event
```

However, I land up losing the timestamp. Output is as below

| min |
| --- |
| 2021-09-28 00:00:00 |

How do I avoid data lose?

Comment: Are you really sure that the data is not already corrupted in the database itself? Try a bare select to see what's actually contained: `select * from event`.

Comment: And just for the case: Run both queries directly in PG admin to exclude the possibility of a client application not correctly evaluating results.

Comment: I would suspect that whichever tool you are using is stripping of that information when you display the data.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid data loss;
You can write the query as [in this DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/PYiMIP3N)

```
SELECT event_timestamp AS min_timestamp
FROM event
WHERE event_timestamp = (SELECT MIN(event_timestamp) FROM event);
```

This will return you the expected output :

| min_timestamp |
| --- |
| 2021-09-28 07:51:20.516921 |

Alternatively;

You can think of casting `event_timestamp` value to varchar using `to_char` to avoid data loss.

```
SELECT to_char(MIN(event_timestamp), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.US') AS min_timestamp
FROM event;
```

The demo is included [with above DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/PYiMIP3N)

This shall also return you the same output

| min_timestamp |
| --- |
| 2021-09-28 07:51:20.516921 |

Comment: Original query runs fine [there](https://dbfiddle.uk/eTrYLxxp), too...

Comment: @Aconcagua;
You are right.
Thanks for bringing to my notice. 
Thinking of OPs client; the `cast`ing may help her. So, I will not modify the answer and I will wait for OP to reply

Comment: @Aconcagua; I see the data is already corrupted in the database. Thanks for bringing to my notice.